# Discrete math - Show that an argument is valid using premises

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I've seen things like this where we are asked to validate some argument in the form below for instance. $$p\rightarrow q$$
$$p \lor r$$ $$r$$

Now, I get why logic is important. Any cursory glance at some proofs can testify to its relevance. But I really have a hard time seeing how it benefits a math major at all when taught in this way. We have to look at this and then argue using things like modus ponens, modus tollens, disjunctive simplification and a bunch of tedious things and we literally never think of it again no matter how many proofs we write or how many problems we tackle. Why are we ever bothering with this?

Is this something like what Lockhart's Lament would decry as sort of sterile and joyless that ultimately ends up being kinda ugly and boring? I don't want to bash any subject here and I hope that's not what it seems like.

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question.

Comment: Haha! But a good rant.

Answer (score 1):

My perspective: I use mathematical logic as the primary organizing force in all the mathematics I do in any subject. Of course, this is as it should be, since mathematical arguments in any subject are mediated through logical relationships — as you point out in your post.

I think the problem you point out is right: logic isn’t taught (in most schools) to be useful. It’s still often couched in philosophical terminology from antiquity. This is indeed a shame, because complicated logical arguments are very difficult to carry out in natural language, but are effortless to manipulate using mathematics.

The style of logic I learned was a calculational, algebraic approach championed by the Dutch mathematicians and computing scientists Edsger Dijkstra, Wim Feijen, and Netty van Gasteren. I’d be happy to give you more information if you’re interested — it’s not clear from your post whether you’re a student or teacher or where your question/rant is coming from.